# lost accss to AWS S3 bucket via policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been trying to get an S3 bucket to be accessible via a single IAM user while having 1 public folder.

While testing policy options, I managed to remove all access to the bucket with the following policy.

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1676745897591",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt167674580000",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3::bucket-name",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

I now cannot access it, including via root user. Any ideas?!

Comment: This article says the root user should still have access to delete the policy from the bucket: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-accidentally-denied-access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IAM policy with "Allow" and "Deny" action can not be attached to the root user. So, you can sign in as root, go to Bucket settings and remove the Bucket policy.

Comment: Thanks for this. It appeared that all access was restricted, but I could still edit the policy!